# Как обратиться к переменной из другого класса?

Tags: java

Main

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JSpinner spinnerOfHeight = new JSpinner(spinnerNumberModelOfHeight);
        mainWindow.add(spinnerOfHeight);

        mainWindow.pack();
        mainWindow.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

CalculateActionListener

```
public class CalculateActionListener implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        double height = spinnerOfHeight.getValue();

    }
}
```

Как получить значение из `spinnerOfHeight` в классе `CalculateActionListener`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Через экземпляр класса. Например

```
public class First {

   int count=0; // переменна

   public First(){}         // конструктор

   public First(int count){ // конструктор

      this.count=count;

   }

}

class Second{

//.....

   First f = new First();

   f.count=1; // нужная переменная

}
```

Comment: @GoodAngel, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Answer (score 1):

Создай конструктор для CalculateActionListener класса, туда и засунь ссылку на свою переменную, ЛИБО в конструктор слушателя отправь JSpinner.

```
class CalculateActionListener implements ActionListener {

    private JSpinner jSpinner;

    CalculateActionListener(JSpinner s) {
        jSpinner = s;
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
//делай что хочеш тут со своим спиннером.

    }
}
```

Comment: для тебя лучше второе.

Comment: код покажи. я не представляю о чём ты